# Styling checkbox if following other checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, siblings

The following code seems to have no effect in Firefox:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: 12px;
    }
```

While this works:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: 12px;
    }
```

Why?

---

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="somename[]" id="somename" value="1"> One<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="somename[]" value="2"> Two<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="somename[]" value="3"> Three<br>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/MyLLZ/ Note that the checboxes must not be nested in other elements

Comment: simple because you have <br> after input tag so CSS for siblings not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the `<br>` tag is the adjacent sibling. You'll need to use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), `~`, to select the sibling `<input>`.

```
input[type="checkbox"] ~ input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the + selector applies to an adjacent sibling. In your case that are the `<br>` tags so there are no adjacent checkboxes..

This works with the interjacent `<br>` tags:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + br + input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

or use the ~ selector:

```
input[type="checkbox"] ~ input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```